# How to configure WCF log tracing through separate components?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, logging

There are several XmlWriterTraceListener-s for each WCF server component.

When user do some action logs are written in different e2e files according to each component. Now we can roundly associate records through separate log files by time-stamp. But it doesn't guarantee accuracy.

The example when such logging is needed:
Some function is evaluating on server and writing logs. We want to know from which client this request was come. Because several clients may work at one time.

May be we should link calls from different components for somehow?
E.g. use something like "token" or "guid" for each callback from client and then bind events from different logs by it? 
Is there maybe any standard option for configuring WCF logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. This is called activity tracing and WCF supports propagating activities. See more here: [Configuring Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx)

As far as I understand your client sends multiple requests to different WCF services in your server. In this case you need client to generate activity ID, then set it as current (use [Correlation Manager class)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.correlationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) and configure your bindings to propagate activities (see link above).